# What are the possible problems with using a mutable object as a dictionary key in Python if the hash is calculated from the unique object ID?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, key, mutable

In Python it is possible to use a mutable object as a dictionary key (such as a user-defined class) as long as the object has a hash function defined. By default, user-defined classes use a function of the object id as their hash, which is guaranteed to be unqiue for a given Python instance. I have seen many posts asking whether it is possible to use mutable objects as dictionary keys, it is, but my question is **should** you use mutable objects as dictionary keys? What are any possible problems that might occur in doing this?

The specific context I am interested in is when a dictionary is used to map objects to other objects, where the key refers to one object and the value is the other object you are mapping to. Using a string id for the key seems like the most obvious approach however in most cases this pattern comes up I then use the string id to get the actual object from somewhere else, probably another dictionary. Instead of using a string id as the key why not cut out the middle man and just use the object itself as the key?

The only problem I could think of with this approach is that you sacrifice defining an equality method on your object which compares by object contents instead of object id. However, as with many things in Python just because you can do something doesn't mean you should so I'm interested in if there are any other potential pitfalls to this approach I should be aware of.

Comment: If equality works by ID too (which is the default behavior), then this is totally fine. Many mutable objects work like this already, including a lot of built-in and stdlib types (for example, functions do this).

Comment: So: are you asking about the case where you use identity, or the case where you don't?  Sometimes even the latter can be made to work, but it's quite error-prone.

Comment: Both I guess. I'm asking whether using mutables as keys is bad practice regardless of the method you use to allow it.